# Biztalk custom pipeline components: XmlSchemaException

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a custom send pipeline with the following components:

Pre-Assemble:

- NO component

Assemble

- XML assembler

Encode

- Custom Component 1
- XML validator
- Custom Component 2

With this configuration, I always get an XmlSchemaException in the "Custom Component 2".
"The exception message is "The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty."

```
Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)
{
  ReadOnlySeekableStream stream = new ReadOnlySeekableStream(pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream());
  XDocument doc;
  //Exception on next line:
  using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
  {
    reader.MoveToContent();
  }
}
```

It's weird because when I remove for example the "Custom Component 1" OR the "XML validator", it works ok. I only get the exception when I have all 3 components in place.

Any idea what I may have to check to make it work with all components?

Thank you and best regards
Michael

Comment: I assume you alter the message in Custom Component 1? Are you sure the Body stream of the message is correct and set to the correct length after altering?

Comment: in the first component, I alter the message and assign a new memory stream to BodyPart.Data (and set the position to 0 of the stream)

Comment: Have you tried logging the stream to string somewhere before this line? You could try and see if there are any issues with it there.

Comment: Yes, I created a StreamReader and used "ReadToEnd()", but this will also throw the same XmlSchemaException (when I have all 3 components in the pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Component 1 adding a XmlElement node with some invalid value e.g. adding empty value for complex type node (record node) `(<Order><price></price></Order> adding empty value after <Order> and then <price> comes)`.
If you are using a map to create Xml before message comes to even Component 1, it might be happening there as well.

- Try removing Custom Component 2 and XmlValidator in validate stage and see how output xml is coming in a folder and try to see it in notepad++.
- Validate your output message of above step with Xml schema

Comment: Hi, I captured the xml after Component 1 and validated it against the XSD in an external tools - it is valid. I finally managed to find 3 nodes that are responsible for the error. They all have attributes, but no node value, e.g.: <ns0:myNode Id="123456"></ns0:myNode> How can I make it work with this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the schema here and the generated xml. Have you tried adding values and these nodes and see if it works or not?